# How do I pass objects to functions in ooRexx?

Tags: function, arguments, oorexx

I'm a long-time mainframe Rexx programmer who is trying out objects in ooRexx. The results are surprising. For example, here is a program:

```
#!/usr/bin/rexx

a = .number~new(3.14)

say "a =" a
say "a~val =" a~val

call say_number a

exit 0

say_number:
procedure
parse arg num

    say "In say_number"
    say "num =" num
    say "num~val =" num~val

return

::class number public

::attribute val get public

::method init   ; expose val ; use arg val
::method new    ; expose val ; use arg val
::method string ; return "'"self~val"'"
```

The result is:

```
> number
a = '3.14'
a~val = 3.14
In say_number
num = '3.14'
    18 *-*   say "num~val =" num~val
     8 *-* call say_number a
REX0097E: Error 97 running /home/tony/bin/.scripts/number line 18:  Object method not found
REX0476E: Error 97.1:  Object "'3.14'" does not understand message "VAL"
```

It appears that the object is being resolved to its string value before it's passed to the `say_number` function. Weird! Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that didn't take long. I changed `parse` to `use` in the function, and everything worked as expected. Per the Reference manual:

> USE ARG retrieves the argument objects provided in a program, routine,
>   function, or method and assigns them to variables or message term
>   assignments.
>
> PARSE assigns data from various sources to one or more variables
>   according to the rules of parsing. ... If you specify UPPER, the
>   strings to be parsed are translated to uppercase before parsing. If
>   you specify LOWER, the strings are translated to lowercase. Otherwise
>   no translation takes place.

Presumably PARSE converts the arguments to a string so that it can change case as requested (or defaulted).